# Sql query in php and viewing secured data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I created a simple message system. registered user can write, view/read messages. 
I am having trouble when it comes in viewing messages. It view all the messages in database.

On my inbox.php -> can read/reply message.
The link of every messages have a variable to get the specific message id.
example: www.web.com/user/message.php?message_id=1234

Now when the link was loaded. It will load the messages/replies. I use this code to get the value of message_id. $message_id= intval($_GET['message_id']);

Unfortunately if I removed/change the value of message_id on the link (ex.www.web.com/user/message.php?message_id=) It load all the messages of users.

Here is the code I used as well as my database structure.
[image: tblmessage]

On my database Parent Post Id are those 'message_parent_post_id' = '0';
If it is a Children post, the column 'message_parent_post_id' should equal to the Parent Post Id.

```
if($message_id= intval($_GET['message_id'])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblmessage WHERE message_id= '{$message_id}'";
    $the_message = db::select_row($sql);//For ParentPostid# 
    $message_post_id = $the_message ['message_id']; }
```

//To load message, here is the problem

View first message (The parent post)

```
<?=date('M d, Y h:m a',strtotime($the_message ['message_date_added']))?>
<br />
<? echo nl2br($the_message ['message_message'])?>
```

View The Replies (Child posts)

```
<? $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblmessage WHERE message_parent_post_id = '{$message_post_id}' ORDER BY message_date_added DESC";?>
<? $u_message = db::select($sql); ?> //children posts
<? foreach ($u_message as $messages){ ?>
<?=date('M d, Y h:m a',strtotime($messages['message_date_added']))?><br />
<?=nl2br($messages['message_message'])?>
```

What I would like here is not to change the database structure yet the changes should be on my code. I would like to view the message of specific user securely.

Comment: does your code really look like that, (every line starting with `<?`)?

Comment: @Dagon, Yes, it is working, I just paste the php code excluding the <div>'s, <textarea> etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the `$message_id` value is coming from the URL via `$_GET['message_id']`, (and you do not have some other security mechanism -- none is present in the code you posted), then any user will be able to edit the URL right in their browser's location box, and thus, see any message.  Data supplied by users from their browsers via `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST`, etc. is always insecure.

Your database structure is fine.  But to view messages securely, you will need some kind of user authentication and a PHP session.

Comment: Hi @CXJ, I am thinking to encrypt the value of $message_id and then decypt it when loading the landing page. However it is not the best option. Would you mind to post some sources here so I can be guided? Or any security mechanism? This is one of my first project.

Comment: @xkevin You need *data validation* and ***permission checking***. If the id is empty and/or missing, **don't do anything, abort.** If the *currently logged in user* does not have permission to view the requested id, **don't do anything, abort.** You simply need to add these checks before you output anything.

Comment: @deceze, Thank you for your comment. I got ideas, I love this stackoverflow.com, when my mind is blocked and don't know what to code I just asked here. My project is now working. The user can only view his/her messages. When user tried to change the id, it will redirect him to another page and exit. Thank you! I wish I can give you + 1.